# cleos create account not working on local node

Tags: cleos, nodeos, wallet

I am facing a problem related to creating account on local node.

**Steps followed:**

- `nodeos` running on a separate terminal.
- wallet is unlocked
- list keys using `cleos wallet keys`. It gives output as:

  `[
  "EOS5auLgLhM3uYWaDEeESKUMfqYsnNcUj2G9xSDuLbmEj4PGfBupL",
  "EOS6MRyAjQq8ud7hVNYcfnVPJqcVpscN5So8BhtHuGYqET5GDW5CV",
  "EOS6aD1hj7hcqktskyMtFKLti62MSaQV4vgb1GMES5cvLmj8s8Jip"
  ]`
- create account for uploading a contract using 
  `cleos create account eosio dev111111111 EOS5auLgLhM3uYWaDEeESKUMfqYsnNcUj2G9xSDuLbmEj4PGfBupL EOS6aD1hj7hcqktskyMtFKLti62MSaQV4vgb1GMES5cvLmj8s8Jip`

**Issue**: It is returning nothing. I did wait for long.

Anyone with the solution, please?

Happy coding :)

Answer (score 2):

Try using

`cleos system newaccount [OPTIONS] creator name OwnerKey [ActiveKey]`

eg:

`cleos system newaccount --stake-net "1.0000 EOS" --stake-cpu "1.0000 EOS" --buy-ram "1.0000 EOS" blockchain11 mynewacc1234 EOS5g4kXUjksMPRV7Eix13NYygW8g4EhA7gsAP3u8ZKzPwp4CMYV6 EOS5g4kXUjksMPRV7Eix13NYygW8g4EhA7gsAP3u8ZKzPwp4CMYV6`

Comment: cleos system newaccount --stake-net "1.0000 EOS" --stake-cpu "1.0000 EOS" --buy-ram "1.0000 EOS" eosio abhitest1234 EOS5auLgLhM3uYWaDEeESKUMfqYsnNcUj2G9xSDuLbmEj4PGfBupL EOS5auLgLhM3uYWaDEeESKUMfqYsnNcUj2G9xSDuLbmEj4PGfBupL

Comment: I tried this (in the comment above)
It gives output as -->

Error 3060002: Account Query Exception
Most likely, the given account doesn't exist in the blockchain.

Comment: Are you using single node test net or public test net?
In the public net, you can only create a new account from an existing account. If you don't have any,  try this [http://jungle.cryptolions.io/#account]
Create an account from there and import those private keys to your wallet.

Comment: I am facing this issue in single node testnet.

I am OK with public testnet i.e. jungle. But the problem is I am unable to see the output of any action e.g. hello name{user}. The transaction gets executed, but only problem is - "in the end it doesn't show output". Pls help??

Comment: I think that in order to see the output of an action, one needs to run on a local node. Is it correct?

Comment: Console logging is suppressed by default.  To see it, add --contracts-console to the nodeos command line.

Comment: It's not working in my case. Is there any other way to see the output on the console?

Comment: How are you printig the message on the console .? mean you  are usig print()  ?

Comment: I am thinking of using eosjs

Answer (score 1):

Can you cross check alias of cleos correctly connected to nodeos

```
 alias cleos='docker exec -it eosio /opt/eosio/bin/cleos --url
 http://127.0.0.1:7777 --wallet-url http://127.0.0.1:5555'
```

Comment: actually I have switched over to working with jungle testnet now and then requesting the actions through eosjs (with JS), eosfactory( with Python)